# Enable-PSRemoting not found

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

One of our test users is reporting that on their test 2k8 system that when they run an elevated Powershell prompt **Enable-PSRemoting** is returning a **'is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again'**
message.

They are in the admins group and as I said the prompt is elevated, and the shell is on to the local computer.

Would anyone know of other things to search for please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt matter if the calling user has admin privileges, the cmdlet should be visible. You're probably not running PowerShell 2.0. You can download it here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929

Do you get any results when you run th following (no result means you're not running v2.0 or previous CTP versions:

$PSVersionTable

A typical result (on Windows 7 ) looks like:

```
PS > $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.4927
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: Scratched my head for a while. Your answer helped me see that I had PowerShell 1.0 installed on my 2008 servers and could not Enable-PSRemoting without the KB above. Cheers!!